# log4net live config changes have no effect

Tags: c#, log4net

We have live system which uses log4net.
Log4net has a separate configuration that is referenced using the appConfig.

We have a request that an additional email address is included.

This has now been added in the external log4net file

```
 <to value="xxx@xxx.com, xxx@xxx.com, xxx@xxx.com"/>
```

the issue is that this change doesnt seem to have any effect... it still continues to email the two original email address and ignored the third.

What i have tried so far :-

- Tweaked the config file so that site resets
- Recycled the app pool
- Restarted the web application

All of which have had no effect.

the config is referenced by:-

```
  <add key="Log4NetConfig" value="~/Config/log4net.config" />
```

Comment: Could you please show the the part of your code that tells your app where the log4net config file is.

Comment: @Jacobr365 This has now been added into the question.

Comment: Do you have the line `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]` or some other version of that in the assembly info.cs file?

Comment: @Jacobr365 hi,  yes,  that line is in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the line:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

And the configuration file is `~/config/log4net.config`, there is definitely a mismatch. I guess you have a second configuration file in you project which is not `~/config/log4net.config` but in the application base directory. You can let your attribute point to the right file of use the file in your application base directory.